# JSP with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to use jsp in my project, but it is difficult.
I put these two dependencies in the pom.xml

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- If you want to use JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then I put these two lines in the aplication.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I created a page with the name "index.jsp" and put that

```
<h1>
   INDEX
</h1>

<p>
   Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur nam, nisi, repudiandae illum 
   ab a aut maxime deleniti voluptas praesentium dicta delectus. Voluptatibus consequuntur 
   necessitatibus hic eum suscipit, sequi autem.
</p>
```

And my controller:

```
package com.example.curso.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And the error when I try to access the route
[image]

Comment: Do you have any template engine on the class-path?

Comment: Based on the screenshot you posted, you already have thymeleaf template engine and enabled as default view resolver(automatically registered if you use spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf)

Comment: I guess you added spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf by mistake. Remove that and also show us the full pom.xml and your folder structure eg: where is the jsp files are located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your stacktrace, it looks Thymeleaf is configured as rendering engine/view resolver. It might be because you have `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` in your classpath and spring boot auto configured it.

JSP support has been dropped from Spring Boot in newer versions. So, you will need manually configure few things to make it work.

If you want to use jsp instead of thymeleaf as your primary rendering engine, remove the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` from your dependency and copy your .jsp files under webapp folder as below:

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

Folder structure:

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── gt
│       │       └── SpringBootWebApplication.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── application.properties
│       └── webapp
│           ├── css
│           │   └── main.css
│           └── jsp
│               └── welcome.jsp
```

Required dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss"/>
    <link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Message: ${msg}</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

@Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String welcome(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("msg", "Hello");
        return "welcome";
    }
```

**Run using `mvn spring-boot:run`**

**Running the @SpringBootApplication's main method might not work**