# Springboot : Controller class is not getting triggered

Tags: spring-boot

For a learning purpose, i have started with a simple spring boot application in eclipse. I was able to run it successfully at http://localhost:8080. Next I added a controller. But i saw that the controller never gets triggered. Any help will be appreciated. The URL I use to access my controller is : http://localhost:8080/conference/greeting

My project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

pom.xml dependencies:

```xml
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Source Code:

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ConferenceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ConferenceApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
    @Controller
    public class GreetingController {
    
        @GetMapping("greeting")
        public String greeting (Map<String, Object> model) {
            model.put("message", "Hello Lok");
            return "greeting";
        }
    }
```

application.properties

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

greeting.jsp:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>Greeting</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1>${message}</h1>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your @Controller doesn't have mapping for `http://localhost:8080/conference/greeting`. Can you try `http://localhost:8080/greeting` ?

Comment: Also, you are missing dependencies for jstl, and jasper. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177451/jsp-with-spring-boot/64180008#64180008 for a working example

Comment: Thanks gitwari. The dependency was missed

Answer (score 0):

Set `server.servlet.context-path=/conference` in application.properties or put the controller class annotation `@RequestMapping("conference")`